# Custom error message in GNU make if required but not otherwise?

Tags: make, gnu-make

In GNU's `make` is it possible to print a custom error message instead of GNU's default one, possibly with the line number as well? I am fine with `make`'s default behavior in all other scenarios.

Here is an example:

```
requirements.txt:
    ls requirements.txt || echo "Download requirements.txt." && false
```

This works; but it is not DRY especially since you see GNU's internal error message as well:

```
% make
Download requirements.txt.
make: *** [Makefile:10: requirements.txt] Error 1
```

I would like to just print:

```
Makefile 10: Please download requirements.txt.
```

(I am trying to use `make` for my `Dockerfile` - not sure if that is a bad idea!)

Comment: You don't need `ls requirements.txt`. The recipe will run when `requirements.txt` is missing. But I don't know how can discard `make`'s error message.

Comment: Yeah @uzsolt, I am doing that for printing this error message actually. Any other cool ideas that can just print this message would work ;-).

Comment: A pattern like "%:" will match everything, but I think you are taking DRY rather too far. A rule like `file1 requirements.txt file2:\n\t@echo Please download $@ >&2 ; exit 1` means you only need to list the files that need to be downloaded. Is this DRY enough for you?

Comment: @icarus, thanks for the pointer. Yes, I think it is not a good thing to do in this case; will try to see some examples of how people use Makefiles with docker.